# How to change the title color of app background?

Tags: android, android-theme

[image: Red title of background app]

As the image shows, the title of APP turns red when it gets background, but not on all phones.Do anyone knows how to change this color?

Comment: Each phone will do this differently, but I believe they take the primaryColor from your styles file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple, go to `res/values/colors.xml` file and change the `colorPrimary` to what color you want:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">YOUR_REQUIRED_COLOR_HERE</color>
```

If you need in `JAVA`, you can also use the answer that @mohammadRezaAbiri gave:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), app_icon);
TaskDescription taskDesc = new TaskDescription(getString(R.string.app_name), bm, getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_600));
MainActivity.setTaskDescription(taskDesc);
```